# Select worksheet by variable

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to activate a worksheet based on a variable. I keep on getting a run time error code 9.

The code I have is:

```
c = 42705 + (b - 1) * 7
Sheets.Add(After:=ActiveSheet).Name = c
    ' Do something here

Worksheets("Import").Activate
    ' Do something here

Worksheets(c).Activate
```

How can I select the worksheet, if the worksheet's name will vary by the iteration?

Comment: The index to `Worksheets` needs to be a string. Convert your integer to a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you do not use `Option Explicit`, thus VBA thinks that `c` is of `Variant` type. Thus, it goes converted to long at first and is not converted to string later. ALWAYS use Option Explicit.

If you add 
`Dim c as String` to your code, it should work. :)

Currently, it is looking for a sheet with index around `40000` and most probably you do not have so many.

In general - if you press the <kbd>Debug</kbd> button on your error message and then select `C` and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+
<kbd>F9</kbd> you would see more info about the selected variable.

Comment: I had Dim c as a variant. Changing to String worked very well. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would reference the worksheet to a variable like below to avoid any issues when changing the name or index.

```
c = 42705 + (b - 1) * 7

Dim newWS As Worksheet
Set newWS = Worksheets.Add(After:=ActiveSheet)
newWS.Name = c
    ' Do something here

Worksheets("Import").Activate
    ' Do something here

newWS.Activate
```

According to VBA Best Practices you should always define and set references to all workbooks and sheets

Comment: I need to read that best practice to help with the correct setups. Thanks for the link.